# Configuring Django runserver to serve static files in a non-app directory?

Tags: django

I'm trying to configure Django to serve static files when using *runserver* (production works fine). Everything works fine for all of the static files that are under an apps directory. The problem comes with static files that are not under a specific app, but are in the final *static* directory. For instance, I have this project structure:

```
/myproject/
/myproject/static/
/myproject/static/css/foo.css
/myproject/app1
/myproject/app1/static/css/bar.css

urls.py
if settings.SERVE_STATIC:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() # one of these may be redundant.

settings.py
SERVE_STATIC = True
PROJECT_ROOT = '/myproject'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),)
INSTALLED_APPS = ('app1',)
```

With these settings, I get the error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain
>   the STATIC_ROOT setting

Which makes sense. I'm telling Django to collect static files, and put them in the same place - which could cause a loop.

If I comment out the STATICFILES_DIRS variable, django will find the static file 'bar.css'. But it does *not* find 'foo.css'.

If I comment out the STATIC_ROOT variable and put back the STATICFILES_DIRS, then it finds the file 'foo.css' - but of course, the 'collectstatic' command will no longer work.

Note - I realize that the '/static' directory is supposed to be empty, but the project I'm on, has files there anyway. :) As long as they're not overwritten by 'collectstatic', it looks like Django runserver should serve them - but it doesn't.

How do I serve the static files under STATIC_ROOT (such as foo.css) when running Django runserver?

Comment: If you run server under developement, you need change `STATIC_ROOT` to a fake directory like `static_fake`. `STATICFILES_DIRS` must be the real directory that contains static files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the files that are in /static/ right now to a different directory -- call it /project-static/, for instance.

Then only include this line in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

(remove the django.views.static.serve view)

And in settings.py, use this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'project-static'),)
```

Then you can put files in /project-static/ directory on your filesystem, the development server will serve them out of the /static/ URL prefix, and in production, `collectstatic` will find them and put them into the /static/ directory where the web server can find them.

Comment: Wow, I'd forgotten I had this question out. :) Looks reasonable, although haven't tried it yet. Basically you're saying `/static/` should always be empty, it's just a destination for _collectstatic_?